# Show first character of selected option in Select

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a select box like this:

```
<select id="selectbox1">
  <option value="s">Second</option>
  <option value="m">Minute</option>
  <option value="h">Hour</option>
  <option value="d">Day</option>
  <option value="w">Week</option>
  <option value="t">monTh</option>
  <option value="y">Year</option>
</select>
```

I want when I select for example 1st option `second` Just `S` appear on select box and so on.
and when its open for another select again show `Second`.

Comment: If `S` is displayed in the collapsed drop down, should `Second` still be displayed if you open the drop down?

Comment: yes again all of options should displayed when drop down opened

Comment: OK, so keep the original text in the expanded drop down

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Add one hidden option and on selection of option take the text of value and insert into hidden option and make it selected forcefully everytime.

```
$('#selectbox1').on('change', function(){                                           
    var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $('.hide').text(option.val()).val(option.val());    
    $('.hide').data('value', option.text());
    $('.hide').attr('selected', true);        
});
```

To get the selected option `value` and `text`, you can this:

```
$(this).find('option:selected').val();
$(this).find('option:selected').data('value');
```

**[DEMO Link](http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/93Hjx)**

Comment: I'm nearly sure it does not work in IE of old versions because they don't even support display: none; for option tag

Comment: you also need to change the `val` apart from `text` for the placeholder option, otherwise getting the selected value would be a nightmare for the op.

Comment: its work but big problem is that `display: none;` not work  for select box `options` in IE

Comment: @user3172276: Honestly I didn't had much exposure much with IE. So, I just gave the solution which I generally use :). However, this discussion (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-en/wIUcwclf7Ms) says that "There's a 
lot of things IE can't do with that tag". Cheers!!!